# set cookie to expire when the user navigates off a webpage

Tags: javascript, cookies

At the moment, my cookie is set to 0, which expires when the user closes the browser. Is there a way to set the cookie to expire when the user leaves my website?

```
Cookie.write('cookieName', 'true',{duration:0});
```

I define 'leave my website' as: navigating to another domain altogether, I want to cookie to stay if they navigate round my site

Comment: Define "leave your website". They could just be navigating to another page on your site or a different site altogether.

Comment: Why not use session cookie? It's more convenient and needs no tricks to work. Also if the user navigates away and comes back in a short amount of time, his data is still valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can't predict when the user will navigate away from the page, you probably need to expire the cookie on the `onbeforeunload` event.

```
window.onbeforeunload = deleteMyCookie;
```

I haven't added the implementation of the `deleteMyCookie` function - but essentially you can overwrite the cookie with an empty string and set the expiration date to the current time.

**Update** - your question edit invalidates this answer. In your case, you don't know when they navigate away from your domain - so you will have to settle for setting a time-based expiry. You could set a reasonably short duration (say, 5 minutes) and move it on each time they load a page on your site - so the cookie would only live a maximum of 5 minutes after they left your domain.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use cookies if they expire as soon as soon as  you navigate away. Javascript variables are more appropriate for these situations, especially since the `onbeforeunload` event does not always fire.

Comment: That depends. If you are making many AJAX requests, the cookies are sent with those requests. I'm not saying that is the use case here, but that is one use for this kind of cookie.

Comment: its only when they navigate to another domain, not just navigate away to another page, i want the cookie to remain as long as they are on my site. But if they go to another site and come back it isnt there anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The cookie standard has not been designed to support that case. Cookies are about HTTP requests and responses (State in a stateless protocol), not about the user using the browser to come and go from one page to another of a different domain and then *expire* something.

That *Expiration* is based on time (or browser session), not on browser tabs sessions, not on users-navigation patterns etc..

If you've got a browser that supports one process per internet domain (maybe as a security feature) and then have a setting to only allow cookies per process, this *might* work without doing anything else. However as this example shows, this is based on the Cookie implementation by the browser and has nothing to do specifically how to set a the cookie in Javascript.